# Change type of authentication using Spring Security SAML Extension

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I've tested the Spring Security SAML Extension for integration in my project and it looks good for me.
But I have one problem with this implementation:
How can I change the authentication to a form based login?

I have an application with a login form. And the requirement is that the authentication goes against an Active Directory Federation Services.
But up to now I found no way in the SAML Extension.

Sorry about this question, but my experience in Spring Security are not very good. I hope the someone here can help me in a simple way.

Best Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

The main point of federation protocols (like SAML) is that user's credentials are only used at the Identity Provider (= ADFS), and are not revealed to the Service Providers. In other words when using SAML you can't have a form login on your SP page.

If you want to combine multiple authentication methods - e.g. SAML + form login against local database, it is of course possible.

Comment: I am trying to achieve similar functionality. Could you please guide me how to do it....

Comment: I am trying to implement the same functionality. From what I have read, it seems that we can't have a form based login/password page at the SP to achieve SAML authentication. So the only option is to use the technique that @vschafer has described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548138/spring-security-different-authentication-methods-depending-on-entity/26553818#26553818)