# Spring Security: Different authentication methods depending on entity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-saml

first post here, hope im doing right.

In a project, we have a scenario where we have a single web application with multiple entities. Currently, the login is managed via default JDBC Spring Security provider, working fine.

For a new requirement, we need that each entity can have their own login method (currently 2 methods would be available, the JDBC one, which is the current one, and the second method would be authentication via SAML, with each entity defining their own IdP, but this is another story)

I need some guidelines on how this can be achieved, I have done some search and I have found providers for different URL's, etc... But not different login methods for the same app and url's depending on the user type or entity.

Is a good approach to have a custom single entry point where we can check the entity user and then use the suitable authentication provider?

Kind regards,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As each of your users might be using a different IDP you will in any case need to determine the username before proceeding with initialization of the authentication process - but you already know this.

One approach to take (similar to what Microsoft is using with the Office 365 for corporate users) is:

- display a login page with fields for standard username + password
- once user enters username and blurs the input field, you make an AJAX call (to your custom API made for this purpose) and fetch information about authentication type + IDP to use for this user
- in case the type is password you simply let user continue with filling in the password field and POST to the same place as you're used to for processing with the JDBC provider
- in case the type is federated authentication you initialize authentication with the correct IDP by redirecting to /saml/login?idp=xyz and continue with the SAML flow

It's possible to avoid any APIs by submitting the form once user enters the username, or let user click a "Continue" button. It would then make sense to use a custom EntryPoint which:

- redirects user to the main login page in case it wasn't provided with a username
- displays either login page with username/password or redirects to the correct IDP, once username was provided

Comment: This is the definitely the approach we will use, the ajax part is a great way to solve it, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vladimír Schäfer I am also trying to achieve the same thing but I need one more authentication mechanism i.e. OAuth Token for authentication. But I am not able to declare multiple <security:http> tag in my spring-security.xml file.
So my question is how to declare multiple url pattern to map login mechanism.

Comment: @ManojP, incase you are still looking for a solution, check the securityContext.xml in spring-security-saml sample application.

Comment: Our UX design prime wants to have a single login/password page from our application (SP) for all the users (local and federated). Is it possible to achieve that with spring security saml extension?

Comment: Yes it is, check the Spring SAML sample application, it includes both local password  + federated authentication.

Comment: @vschafer, yes it does. However, there are different urls for local and federated authentication. I am looking for a design where I can add federated authentication as another AuthenticationProvider in spring security

Comment: Check history in the repo, it was previously unified.

Comment: I am stuck on step 1:
> display a login page with fields for standard username + password
My app redirects to the IDP login page. It's a Grails 2.5.6 app using Spring Security Core and Web 3.2.9, and Spring Security Core SAML 1.0.1. It looks like SAMLEntryPoint.commence(...) is initializing initializeSSO(...)  which sends a auth request to the default IDP. How do I change the flow to allow the user to enter user name so I can initiate the appropriate auth?